# Ninject / MVC4 - integration test of a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, integration-testing

It may be useful to write an integration test for a controller.
It is not clear how to instantiate a controller if its dependencies are managed by Ninject.

Please note it is not a unit test - I want to test a complete controller with all dependencies.
I am using MVC 4, NInject 3 and MbUnit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to find an answer on SO but I could not so I am sharing my solution.

```
public class SearchControllerTest 
{
    private SearchController searchController;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices(kernel); 

        searchController = kernel.Get<SearchController>();         
    }

    //Tests
}
```

Comment: Actually my answer was the same as yours

Comment: @Andrei No, when the question is "How do instantiate a controller with Ninject?" then "Use Ninject to instantiate the controller" is hardly a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 2):

If controller dependencies are managed by Ninjet, you should instantiate your controller with help of Ninject Kernel, and all of your dependencies will be in place.